# Are Expressjs req, res objects garbage collected after the request?

Tags: node.js, express

Are expressjs req, res objects garbage collected after the request goes through and res.send() is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be cleaned up once nothing is referencing them.  If you still have code that has a reference out there to `req` or `res`, then they will remain until your code is done with them.  That is not necessarily when you are finished sending the response.

Comment: So, if I reference an object to it, for example: req.x = app.x, the req object should be garbage collected anyway ?

Comment: @litenull, Yeah that would be fine.  The issue is if you go the other way around.  A simple example is setting a global `globals.x = req`.  `req` will never go away.